# Paho MQTT cleaning in abortwrite for socket error in C

Tags: c, sockets, mqtt, paho

I have been trying to send some information using MQTT from an embedded device(RFID reader). This device pushes the data very frequently(~25-30 data for every second). When I start the process in the device, it runs without any issues for ~9-10 hours. Then the process gets killed and when checked the logs, it says

```
cleaning in abortwrite for socket 5
Failed to connect, return code -1

cleaning in abortwrite for socket 4
Failed to connect, return code -1
```

Is this problem MQTT or any memory related?Can someone help me out with this?

Please find the below code I have used

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include "MQTTClient.h"

    int main()
    {

    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;

    MQTTClient_create(&client, "tcp://mqtt1.mindlogic.com:1883", "ExampleClientPub",
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    pubmsg.payload = buf;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = (int)strlen(buf);
    // pubmsg.payloadlen = sizeof *antenna_id;

    pubmsg.qos = 1;

    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, "mqtt-ex", &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n""on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",(int)(10000L/1000), "Hello World!", "MQTT-Examples", "ExampleClientPub");
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, 10000L);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);

    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say that the code runs for 9-10 hours, but the code you have posted looks like it connects, sends on message then disconnects? If the problem is with the code running for a long time you might need to post more code. As an aside, if you are concerned about a potential memory leak you could monitor the memory usage and see if the memory usage is increasing.

Comment: To expand on @castro's point, at that rate of messages you really should have a persistent connection to the broker sending all the messages.

Comment: are you expecting us to guess as to the contents of the 'home grown' header file: `MQTTClient.h`

Comment: Regarding; `pubmsg.payload = buf;`  What is `buf`?  it is never declared in the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, 10000L);`  why isn't the returned value: `rc` being checked to assure that the completion occurred before a timeout occurred.  That code is assuming that the transmission was successful,  It is NEVER a good idea to assume anything when coding

Comment: regarding; `conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;`  This conflicts with the code immediately destroying the connection